# Line Break (\n) is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to split the values (each item is separated by pipe symbol) and display each value in new line. I tried to add '/n' between each value but, the following code is not working as expected.

In my case, the values are in Location field.

Example: 'Location A|Location B|Location C|Location D'

```js
//this data comes from server via ajax response

var rows = [];

var row1 = {};
row1.Name = 'Test User A';
row1.Location = 'Location A|Location B|Location C|Location D';
row1.Status = 'Success';

rows.push(row1);


//this code runs after receving the ajax call

$.each(rows, function(i, row){
  
  $('#StatusDataBody').append(GetRowTemplate(row));
  
  });


function GetRowTemplate(row){
  
  return "<tr>" +
                "<td class='text-center col-md-2'>" + row.Name + "</td>" +
                "<td class='col-md-3'>" + row.Location.split('|').join(',\n ') + "</td>" +
                "<td class='col-md-2'>" + row.Status + "</td>" +              
              "</tr>"; 
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <table class="table table-condensed table-custom">
                    <caption class="title-color">
                        <strong>Status Report</strong> | 
                <button type="button" id="DownloadStatusReportBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-xs disabled" title="Click here to download details"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>&nbspDownload Detail</button>
                    </caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                            
                            <th class="text-center col-md-2">Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center col-md-3">Location</th>
                            <th class="text-center col-md-2">Status</th>          
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7">
                                <div id="StatusDataContainer">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                                        <tbody id="StatusDataBody"></tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**Expectation:**

The values should be displayed as shown below,

```
Location A,
Location B,
Location C,
Location D
```

I am wondering why the values in location are not displaying in new line... Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: for line break in html use `<br>`

Comment: instead of '\n' use <br>

Comment: `\n` has no significance in HTML ... look at your TH elements, separated by newlines, yet they go across the page in the resulting web page, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<br />` and not `\n`

```js
//this data comes from server via ajax response

var rows = [];

var row1 = {};
row1.Name = 'Test User A';
row1.Location = 'Location A|Location B|Location C|Location D';
row1.Status = 'Success';

rows.push(row1);


//this code runs after receving the ajax call

$.each(rows, function(i, row){
  
  $('#StatusDataBody').append(GetRowTemplate(row));
  
  });


function GetRowTemplate(row){
  
  return "<tr>" +
                "<td class='text-center col-md-2'>" + row.Name + "</td>" +
                "<td class='col-md-3'>" + row.Location.split('|').join('<br />') + "</td>" +
                "<td class='col-md-2'>" + row.Status + "</td>" +              
              "</tr>"; 
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <table class="table table-condensed table-custom">
                    <caption class="title-color">
                        <strong>Status Report</strong> | 
                <button type="button" id="DownloadStatusReportBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-xs disabled" title="Click here to download details"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>&nbspDownload Detail</button>
                    </caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                            
                            <th class="text-center col-md-2">Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center col-md-3">Location</th>
                            <th class="text-center col-md-2">Status</th>          
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7">
                                <div id="StatusDataContainer">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                                        <tbody id="StatusDataBody"></tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetRowTemplate(row){

  return "<tr>" +
                "<td class='text-center col-md-2'>" + row.Name + "</td>" +
                "<td class='col-md-3'>" + row.Location.split('|').join(',<br> ') + "</td>" +
                "<td class='col-md-2'>" + row.Status + "</td>" +              
              "</tr>"; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML more than one white-space symbol, most `\#` symbols are ignored (like `\t`, `\n`...).
New line symbol is `<br/>` in HTML.

Also, it's not `/n` but `\n` or `\r\n` or `\r` (system dependent).

Comment: @JaromandaX What do you mean `\n doesn't work`? In source code you will see new lines with `\n`.